# ShareLaTeX Bibliography in ApJ format

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, citing, natbib, sharelatex

I am trying to use ShareLaTex to compile my bibliography in the Astrophysical Journal (ApJ) format. The document compiles in ApJ format just fine, but the bibliography is compiled in some generic format and `\cite{}` and `\citep{}` do not work as expected, with my references replaced by the usual question marks.  Here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[apj]{emulateapj}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\bibliographystyle{apj}
\bibliography{P1640_AGES}

\begin{document}

...

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems to me that the problems is due to the use of both `natbib` and `biblatex`.

Comment: Commenting out natbib doesn't have any change, and conversely commented out biblatex caused the bibliography to disappear entirely

Comment: If you comment out `biblatex` you should move the `\bibliography` command in place of `\printbibliography`.

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems:

1. The file `apj.bst` is not present by default in ShareLaTeX (either you request ShareLaTeX to include it in the available packages or upload it directly. I got a copy of it from http://www.astro.virginia.edu/coolflow/apj.bst)
2. The file mixes the use of two reference/bibliography managers `natbib` and `biblatex`. The usage should be:

**natbib**

```
\documentclass[apj]{emulateapj}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apj}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
...
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

**biblatex**

```
\documentclass[apj]{emulateapj}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
...
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I don't know if there are already predefined `biblatex` styles for APJ, and more options might be needed (e.g., `author-year`) for `biblatex`.'

Comment: Back in December 2013 I've tried to build upon (read: hack into) the `author-year` style of plain `biblatex` and make a style tailored for ApJ. An updated version of the code can be found at https://github.com/EdwinChan/biblatex-apj.

Answer (score 0):

4 years into the future and the answer is finally here. You need to use the `iop` format for emulateapj, as it uses the `chicago` format by default. Your code should look like this:

```
\documentclass[apj,iop]{emulateapj}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\bibliographystyle{apj}
\bibliography{P1640_AGES}

\begin{document}

...

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: But `\bibliographystyle{apj}` *and* `\printbibliography` is still wrong. Loading `natbib` and `biblatex` will also cause an error.